# How to enable preview feature in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm using sealed class in Java 16 and I got an error:

```
Sealed Type is a preview feature and disabled by default. Use --enable-preview to enable
```

How to enable preview features in VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open standalone Java files (i.e. which have no Eclipse/Maven/Gradle settings), preview features are enabled by default. Configure the `java.configuration.runtimes` preference in your **User Settings.json**:

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-16",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-16",
    "default": true
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-15",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-15",
  },
],
```

Eclipse/Maven/Gradle project settings view [Enabling Java preview features](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Enabling-Java-preview-features).

Comment: Is there anyway to configure it to JavaSE 17?

Comment: I'm trying to use it

Comment: the Phase Two version

Comment: @KhánhBảo. You can change path to java17 in the above settings then see if it works.

Comment: @KhánhBảo. See my answer update, you can add different jdk options in the setting `"java.configuration.runtimes"`, change the location of `"default": true` to specify which jdk is used in projects.

Comment: I mean, JavaSE-17 is not a valid value

Comment: @KhánhBảo. Got it! I test in my project and the same warning occurs in my project. That's because `Valid values: "J2SE-1.5", "JavaSE-1.6", "JavaSE-1.7", "JavaSE-1.8", "JavaSE-9", "JavaSE-10", "JavaSE-11", "JavaSE-12", "JavaSE-13", "JavaSE-14", "JavaSE-15", "JavaSE-16"` and javaSE-17 is not included in above. You can specify `path` as java17 but `name` it as JavaSE-15 or something else in above valid values, then you run the project, it will use java.exe of JavaSE-17.